# Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to upload an app to firebase, using the following command:

```
firebase serve --only functions,hosting --project project name
```

however, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
```

On the IAM-Admin page, I have all permissions set to either Owner or Editor. What am I doing wrong and how do I run the firebase app?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a 403 error on the browser when serving Firebase Hosting locally.

I tried changing the port number by

```sh
firebase serve --port 50080 --only hosting
```

Then the page was shown. I use firebase-tools v9.23.0 on macOS 12.